# If socket created by ServerSocket.accept() is closed but the socket on client side isn't, will ServerSocket.accept() accept it again?

Tags: java, sockets

Let say `A` is Server and `B` is Client. `B` create a socket `b` to Server `A` and  `ServerSocket.accept()` create a corresponding socket `a` for the client `B` now if `a` is closed by Server `A` but client `B` haven't closed its socket `b` and `ServerSocket.accept()` still running then will `ServerSocket.accept()` create another socket `c`for client B again?

Comment: What do you mean by `ServerSocket.accept() is still running`? Do you mean it is blocking waiting for a new connection?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  The way I read it is as follows: _If the SERVER closes its connected socket, but the client doesn't and the server still has an outstanding accept(), will the connection be re-established without the client taking any action_.  **Is that what you intended to ask?**

Comment: @Jim Garrison yes that is what I want to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

When *either* the Server `A` or Client `B` closes the connection, the connection is closed for the sockets on both. The client will need to initialize a new connection in order for a new socket `c` to be created. `ServerSocket.accept()` will only return when the client explicitly requests a new connection.

Comment: I have. Since it is a TCP socket, if either side closes the socket, then it closes for both. A new connection will only be created if the client issues another connection request. But if you disagree @JimGarrison, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: The problem is the question is too ambiguous. I read it as asking if the SERVER closes its connected socket, but the client doesn't and the server still has an outstanding `accept()`, will the connection be re-established without the client taking any action, in which case the answer is no.

Comment: Given the OP's clarification in a comment, I suggest you edit your answer to match the actual question.

Comment: @JimGarrison Alright will do. I am still unsure of what is best practices / allowed when editing an answer.

Comment: So that mean to re-establish connection, the Client must close its socket too and re-create new socket to the server?

Comment: The question is clearer, update your answer without regard for previously wrong information.  Make the answer useful for future readers.

Comment: Note: Calling `close()` on one else doesn't result in `isClosed()` on the other and that end can continue to read any buffered data.